# Get rid of "Lighthouse" tab in chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I have this tab

[image]

How do I get rid of it or hide it?

Comment: You can only move it to the bottom drawer (right-click its title) so it won't be visible unless the drawer is shown.